# SQL Most Recent Register FROM Second Table by Id

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I have 2 tables (Opportunity and Stage). I need to get each opportunity with the most recent stage by StageTypeId.

Opportunity: Id, etc
Stage: Id, CreatedOn, OpportunityId, StageTypeId.

Let's suppose I have "opportunity1" and "opportunity2" each one with many Stages added.

By passing the StageTypeId I need to get the opportunity which has this StageTypeId as most recent.

I'm trying the following query but it´s replicating the same Stage for all the Opportunities.

It seems that it's ignoring this line:  "AND {Stage}.[OpportunityId] = ID"

```
SELECT {Opportunity}.[Id] ID,
       {Opportunity}.[Name],
       {Opportunity}.[PotentialAmount],
       {Contact}.[FirstName], 
       {Contact}.[LastName],
       (SELECT * FROM 
            (
                SELECT {Stage}.[StageTypeId]
                  FROM {Stage}         
                 WHERE {Stage}.[StageTypeId] = @StageTypeId  
                   AND {Stage}.[OpportunityId] = ID       
                 ORDER BY {Stage}.[CreatedOn] DESC
            ) 
        WHERE ROWNUM = 1) AS StageTypeId     
 FROM {Opportunity}
 LEFT JOIN {Contact} 
   ON {Opportunity}.[ContactId] = {Contact}.[Id]
```

Thank you

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: It's Oracle....

Answer (score 0):

Most of DBMS support `fetch first` clause So, you can do :

```
select o.*
from Opportunity o
where o.StageTypeId = (select s.StageTypeId 
                       from Stage s
                       where s.OpportunityId = o.id
                       order by s.CreatedOn desc
                       fetch first 1 rows only
                      );
```

Comment: I think there is something wrong, the StageTypeId is in Stage table not opportunity table. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

you can try below way all dbms will support

```
   select TT*. ,o*. from
   (
   select s1.OpportunityId,t.StageTypeId from Stage s1 inner join

    (select StageTypeId,max(CreatedOn) as createdate Stage s
    group by StageTypeId
    ) t
    on s1.StageTypeId=t.StageTypeId and s1.CreatedOn=t.createdate 
   ) as TT inner join Opportunity o on TT.OpportunityId=o.id
```